# Can I use if-else statement nested in for loop on an Array in Python

Tags: python

For this question I will simplify what I am doing, say this is my array

```
food = ['chicken', 'banana', 'milk', 'OJ', 'pork', 'apple']
```

now I want to print off the list of what type of food my objects are, fruit, meat or drink. Can I?

```
for i in food:
    if i==1 or i==5:
        print("Fruit")
    elif i==0 or i==4:
        print("meat")
    else:
        print("drink")
```

However when I do this it just prints out

```
drink
drink
drink
drink
drink
drink
```

How do I get it to print out?

```
meat
fruit
drink
drink
meat
fruit
```

Comment: Have you tried to print out `i` in your loop? That should give you the answer to your problem. You might be interested to explore `enumerate`.

Comment: `i` is the list element, not the index.

Comment: Why would you want to write something like this? Hard-coding specific list indexes is horrible design.

Comment: Did you look at: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: This is terrible data structuring. A dict would be much better. For example: `{'meat': ['chicken', 'pork'], 'fruit': [bananna', 'apple'], 'drink': ['banana', 'OJ']}`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looping over `food` with a `for i in food` loop, `i` is going to be an item in the loop, which is a string. Since you're checking if `i == 1`, etc., it's always going to return false because the `i` is never going to be an int. It's always going to be a `str`, since the only items in `food` are `str`s.

You can instead loop over `enumerate(food)` instead of `food`, so you can have `i` (the index of the item) and `item` (the item itself) for each loop iteration.

This code will work as you expect:

```py
for i, item in enumerate(food):
    if i==1 or i==5:
        print("Fruit")
    elif i==0 or i==4:
        print("meat")
    else:
        print("drink")
```

If you don't plan to ever use `item`, replace it with an undercore (`_`), like this:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(food):
    ...
```

Comment: You never use `item`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `for i in food` it just returns every element of the list. To return the index use the combination of `len` and `range`

```
for i in range(len(food)):
    if i==1 or i==5:
        print("fruit")
    elif i==0 or i==4:
        print("meat")
    else:
        print("drink")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `for i in <collection>:` it gives you the elements directly. In other words, `i` is `chicken` then `banana` etc.

You could do `for i in range(len(food):` so that `i` will be the indices you are looking for.

Another option would be
`for i, item in enumerate(food):` which will give you both the index and the actual item. You are not currently using the item itself, just its index, but if you need both at once in the future, this is the way to do it.

Comment: I hadn't even seen any other answers haha. I was just on a phone and typing really slowly

Answer (score 0):

Because you assign `i` like `for i in food`, on each iteration, `i` will be the next element in `food`, e.g. `i` will be `'chicken'`, `'banana'`, `'milk'`, and so on. To see this in action, try adding a line `print(i)` at the top of the `for` loop's body.

It seems like you want `i` to hold the value of the *index* you are currently on. To iterate over the indices of `food`, you can do `for i in range(len(food))`. The `range` function will generate values from `0` to `len(food) - 1`, inclusively. Check out this link to learn more about the `range` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range

Answer (score 0):

As Mr.T has pointed out in the comments, you should try printing out i in your loop to see what i actually is. i is referring to each individual item in your list, not a number. If you were to print i in your for loop, it would print the value of each individual item in your list, not the index number. Meaning i is referring to 'chicken' the first time around the loop, not the index number 0. You could try something like:

```
food = ['chicken', 'banana', 'milk', 'OJ', 'pork', 'apple']
count = 0
for i in food:
    if count==1 or count==5:
        print("Fruit")
    elif count==0 or count==4:
        print("Meat")
    else:
        print("drink")
    count += 1
```